# How to prevent a post from being deleted?

Tags: plugins, posts, user-roles, permissions, cms

For auditing issue, I only want a post can be trashed, but not deleted - for all users.

So I have a plugin like

```
add_action('before_delete_post', function($id) {
        wp_die(0);
    });
```

But seems not all delete action are ajax, so it will be show a black screen with return an error page with result "0"

Feature wise the above code is ok, but are there any better way?

Answer (score 10):

Don't let the action die, just do a redirect (to wherever you'd like):

```
function wpse_92155_before_delete_post() {
    wp_redirect(admin_url('edit.php'));
    exit();
} // function wpse_92155_before_delete_post
add_action('before_delete_post', 'wpse_92155_before_delete_post', 1);
```

Comment: Qui old, I know, but how this work with AJAX calls and XML-RPC requests? I don't think that in these cases, redirection is the right solution.

Answer (score 5):

I would use the hook `before_delete_post` as the last layer of protection against deletion (using @tf's solution, and which is the correct Answer).

And first remove the "Delete" options from sight. The following hides the *Bulk Actions* and the *Empty Trash* button, and removes the *Delete Permanently* row action.

[image: before]

With this code:

```
add_action( 'admin_head-edit.php', 'hide_delete_css_wpse_92155' );
add_filter( 'post_row_actions', 'hide_row_action_wpse_92155', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'page_row_actions', 'hide_row_action_wpse_92155', 10, 2 );

function hide_delete_css_wpse_92155()
{
    if( isset( $_REQUEST['post_status'] ) && 'trash' == $_REQUEST['post_status'] ) 
    {
        echo "<style>
            .alignleft.actions:first-child, #delete_all {
                display: none;
            }
            </style>";
    }
}

function hide_row_action_wpse_92155( $actions, $post ) 
{
    if( isset( $_REQUEST['post_status'] ) && 'trash' == $_REQUEST['post_status'] ) 
        unset( $actions['delete'] );
        
    return $actions; 
}
```

This is the result:

[image: after]

#### Note of interest

There is no hook `cpt_row_actions`. The hooks `page_row_actions` and `post_row_actions` are [applied if the post type is hierarchical or not](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-posts-list-table.php#L565), respectively.

Comment: Mkay. +1 to both you and @tf. I couldn't upvote his one-liner before, because further information pending I could have only assessed its quality by further research on the subject. Yet another answer thoroughly put into context.

Answer (score 5):

This is an old post, but for others still seeking an answer, I think there's a more elegant way – filtering `user_has_cap`. This allows you to remove the users rights to delete a post under whatever circumstances you determine. Filtering `user_has_cap` automatically removes the UI elements and the action in one simple function and works no matter how the attempt to delete is made. See [this post](https://www.wp-code.com/wordpress-snippets/prevent-wordpress-from-deleting-a-post/) for more details.

```
add_filter ('user_has_cap', 'wpcs_prevent_deletion', 10, 3);
 
function wpcs_prevent_deletion ($allcaps, $caps, $args) {
    if (isset($args[0]) && isset($args[2]) && $args[0] == 'delete_post') {
        $post = get_post ($args[2]);
        // Insert your logic here
        if ($prevent_deletion) {
            $allcaps[$caps[0]] = false;
        }
    }
    return $allcaps;
}
```