# How to only allow post to be deleted if custom field doesn't exist

Tags: posts, custom-field, customization

I have looked at both the delete_post and before_delete_posts.  Neither of these hooks actually allow me to perform a check and then tell wordpress not to delete the post.  Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hook into `before_delete_post` and [redirect before completing the deletion](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/92155/how-to-prevent-a-post-from-being-deleted).

```
add_action('before_delete_post', function($post_id) {

   // Get custom field
   $field = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'key', 'true');

   // Redirect if field is empty
   if (!$field) {
       wp_redirect(admin_url('edit.php'));
       exit();
   }

}, 1);
```

Comment: Thanks I will check this out when I get to working on those functions.  I must have been up late that night or misunderstood something or maybe it was the fact I didn't know redirecting would solve the problem.  It makes perfect sense so I'm accepting it before hand.  Wordpress makes developing a dream.